# Consuming a multipart/form-data via RESTful CXF

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jackson, multipartform-data

I've been working in a webservice that consumes and produces JSON files using Apache CXF in conjuction with Jackson. 
 However, one of the service's methods should be able to save an uploaded image from a mobile application that makes a multipart/form-data POST request to my webservice, and I don't know how to treat this kind of content-type within my context. We usually create "Request" and "Response" objects to consume and produce the JSON, however, I'm afraid this would not work for this case.

This is the Request format:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data
"Description": text/plain
"Path": text/plain
"Image": image/jpeg
```

How to correctly consume this kind of request and save the image server-side?

---

**[EDIT]**

I managed to consume multipart/form-data by using this:

```
public returnType savePicture(
                @Multipart(value = "mode", type = "text/plain") String mode,
                @Multipart(value = "type", type = "text/plain") String type,
                @Multipart(value = "path", type = "text/plain") String path
                @Multipart(value = "image", type = "image/jpeg") Attachment image
            ) 
    {
```

However, when trying to consume the following POST request:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="mode"

T
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="type"

M
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="path"

c:/img/
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

imgdata
--AaB03x--
```

I'm getting the following error:

> javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart.MultipartReadException: No multipart with content id **type** found, request content type : multipart/form-data;boundary=AaB03x

When I consume only **mode**, for instance, it works fine. It only breaks for 2 or more parameters. Any idea for why is that wrong?

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246579/jax-rs-with-cxf-rest-assured-handling-multiparam-file-upload   2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913382/uploading-multiple-files-and-metadata-with-cxf     Consult these

Comment: 3. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll try to make out something useful from them. I managed to consume the text/plain, I'm just having trouble with the image now, but I haven't tried with inputStream like link 1 suggests.

Comment: Not yet, to be honest. I've editted the original post with my progress, but so far, no luck consuming multiple parts.

Comment: i have never used multipart in my rest services... i ll give this a try and let you know in few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we found the problem, and it was related to the format of the request. The correct format should have been:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="mode"

T--AaB03x

content-disposition: form-data; name="type"

M--AaB03x

content-disposition: form-data; name="path"

c:/img/--AaB03x

content-disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

imgdata--AaB03x--
```

Changing to this format allowed me to consume the other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue sometime back.

The following code did the trick for me

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public void yourMethod(<params>) throws Exception {
}
```

In short, it is I think the `@Consumes` annotation you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

For consuming multipart form data. use @consumes tag & provide "multipart/form-data" along with value parameter like

@Consumes(value = "multipart/form-data")

refer 
https://jnorthr.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/http-header-content-type-and-encodings/