# Upload image to server using POST

Tags: java, post, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I know that there are some similar questions to this one on the site, and I've read most of them. I've also Googled for a solution, but am still having issues.

So, in my project I need to catch multipart post requests that are used to send mixed data (an image, two strings (company, type), date data (month, year) and a few integers) from a client. Upon receiving this request I need to change contrast and brightness of the image, and modify the color to gray tones.

For debugging I use Postman Chrome Extension, and for now I am only focusing on sending the image. I've tested sending the request in different ways, in half of them I get a "404 Not Found" error, in the other half wrong data is returned (mostly array of 0). Below is the code used in my resource method:

```
@Component
@Path("/code")
@Produces("application/json")
public class EncodeResource extends BasicResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/encode")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public String encodeImage(
            @FormDataParam("image") InputStream imageInputStream) {
        BufferedImage imageBuffer = null;
        try {
            imageBuffer = ImageIO.read(imageInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (imageBuffer != null)
            return okResponse(<some parameters>);
        else
            return errorResponse(<some parameters>);
    }
}
```

ImageInputStream contains some byte array, but ImageIO.read() always returns *null*. I tried different images with different extensions (which imageio can read by default, checked it), but got the same result. As I think, it happens cause of there are some "unnecessary" information in my inputStream, so imageio.read() can't convert it into any type of image. I've suddenly found it, when changed InputStream to File:

```
@FormDataParam("image") File imageInputStream
```

...and then checked saved by tomcat .tmp file. It looked like that:

> ------WebKitFormBoundary4nC1XD4cevbbRh7A
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="1.jpg">
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> (a lot of bytes)
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary4nC1XD4cevbbRh7A--

And of course imageio.read() returned *null*.

Summing up all of that, I have 2 questions actually:

1. Why did I get 404 error and how can i fix it? For example, I tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/) and like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271573/consuming-a-multipart-form-data-via-restful-cxf). And I had to delete the second @FormDataParam from [here](http://puspendu.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/restful-webservice-file-upload-with-jersey/) to receive at least something. Can it be cause of the Postman "specific" form-data requests?
2. Why did I get the wrong data? Maybe I can parse received file and get "correct" byte array? Or something else?..

Comment: Your resource method looks fine. Are you sure the image you are testing with is actually a JPEG?

Comment: What is the JAX-RS implementation that are you using? Jersey, RESTEasy, Wink?

Comment: 1. Test-image was created in Paint and saved as JPEG...

2. In code above I used Jersey.