# Webservice consuming image from Android camera only on lower resolutions

Tags: java, android, image, web-services, cxf

I have a [webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271573/consuming-a-multipart-form-data-via-restful-cxf) running and ready to consume images produced by my Android tablet camera (Samsumg Galaxy TAB 10.1).

It works perfectly when consuming images taken at **1024x768** resolution (0.8M). However, when using the tablet's highest resolution (**2048x1536**, or 3.2M), the image saved simply does not work. It saves a broken image file with 0kb size.

This is the code related to the image-saving in the webservice:

```
public static void saveFile(final InputStream file, final String filePath) throws IOException {

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath.trim()));

    int read = 0;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

    while ((read = file.read(bytes)) != -1) {

        out.write(bytes, 0, read);

    }

    file.close();

    out.flush();

    out.close();

}
```

I've already tried increasing the byte array size, but it didn't help.

The `file` variable is produced like this:

```
final InputStream image = data.getImage().getDataHandler().getInputStream();
```

Where `data` is a object consumed via a multipart request made by the webservice to Android, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271573/consuming-a-multipart-form-data-via-restful-cxf).

Any ideas?